# How to remove FSCaleander Future Date background Blue Color After comming into current date?

Tags: ios, swift, fscalendar

i am select future date from the FSCalendar its highlighted future date, After i need to reload or refresh the calendar . calendar coming into current date , In current date will showing into red color and future date will highlighted into blue color.

My senario in calendar after coming into current date , the current date only shown highlighted remain will be show normal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i am using FSCalendar Podfile to show calendar .. after loads the calendar i had selected future date for example today 15th i selected 17th and i am coming into  current today date . after getting today day future date also showing highland .. my senario when i am current date , current date only highlited future date shw normally.

Answer (score 0):

### **Storyboard**

[image]

### **programmatically**

```
myCalendar.appearance.todayColor = .white
myCalendar.appearance.titleTodayColor = .black
```

[image]